# Git / Azure Repos - is it possible to block commits on master if a certain branch exist?

Tags: git, azure-devops

The following situation:
When we create a release candidate, we make a branch release/*.

This is then tested and if necessary fixes are made on this branch.

After that it is merged back into master and tagged.

In between, no commits may be made to master.

Is there a technical way to prevent this or at least to give a warning if a branch with the pattern release/* exists?

Comment: Why would you have to stop work on master? One of the strong points of git is how easy it is to have multiple branches where devs can work on.

Comment: because in our process we make a version tag after merging release branch back to master. commit in between would lead to a wrong content behind the tag. every work after crafting the rc is not scope of this version and should be merged after this tag. So we dont merge anything in this (little) timeframe. Also we merge release branch in pipelines, if rc fixes and PRs would create merge conflicts, the workflow would break..

Comment: I don't quite understand your issue, why are you tagging the rc branch after merging into master. I do not see why this is needed. Why not just immediately tag the rc commit when you created the branch? Also, I do not see why you could not reject fixes/prs that contain merge conflicts, surely your ci should be able to handle that.

Comment: we tag the master branch not release with the version tag after merging. and if we continue commit on master in the time we are testing and fixing rc, the tag contains features of the next version. Our Pipelines merge the release branches back to the master branches, if there are merge conflics then they fail. Its our process, so master has to be untouched while release

Answer (score 1):

You can write any script you like and make it run on certain conditions. It’s called Git Hooks. Lots of information is available on them, such as on https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks